# Using setRGB() required IntArray in Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, rgb, bufferedimage

I want to change color of a pixel in Kotlin. I get a pixel, want to set new values for it but I get an error in setRGB method that it requires IntArray! but found Array:

```
val c: Int = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)
val color = Color(c)

val newColor = Array<Int>(3) { color.red; 0; 0 }
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, 0, 0, newColor, 0, 0)
```

Also, I am writing code in Kotlin/Java and cannot find detailed explanation how does setRGB() method work. I know from Intelij IDE that parameters are: setRGB(x, y, width, height, IntArray for rgb color, offset, scansize).

But what is width, height? Is it dimensions of a picture? Why do they matter if I only change one pixel?

And how do I pass new color to setRGB() method correctly as IntArray?

Comment: But how do I convert Color type to int then? For example Color(255, 0, 0)?

Comment: I posted an answer below.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That was the thing I struggled on and started to look for another function constructor. It fixed now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only changing one pixel (at a time), you should use the `setRGB(int x, int y, int aRGB)` method. Don't bother with arrays at all.

I don't normally program Kotlin, so the syntax may not be 100% correct, but anyway:

```
val c: Int = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)
val color = Color(c)

val newColor = Color(color.red, 0, 0)
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, newColor.getRGB())
```

---

That said, the `width` and `height` parameters of the `setRGB` method that takes an `int` array, is the height and with of the region you want to set (and usually `offset == 0` and `scansize == width`) . You typically use this only to set multiple pixels. To set a single pixel using it, the values should be simply `1, 1` (I borrowed the `intArrayOf` part from @Tom's answer):

```
val newColor = intArrayOf(color.red, 0, 0)
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, 1, 1, newColor, 0, 1)
```

This should also work. But I think it's less elegant and probably slower due to array bounds checking and copying.

Answer (score 1):

`setRGB` expect a primitive `int[]`

In kotlin the java equivalent of `int[]` is `IntArray` (https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-int-array/)

So you should change the creation of `val newColor` to:

```kotlin
val newColor = intArrayOf(color.red, 0, 0)
```

Full example:

```kotlin
val c: Int = bufferedImage.getRGB(x, y)
val color = Color(c)

val newColor = intArrayOf(color.red, 0, 0)
bufferedImage.setRGB(x, y, 0, 0, newColor, 0, 0)
```

For more info regarding the function you can refer to the javadoc: [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int[],%20int,%20int)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#setRGB(int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%5B%5D,%20int,%20int))

Comment: Thank you for the docs, couldnt find these ones. But they are not the easiest to navigate I must say...